# Holomorphic functions and modules.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $U\subseteq{\mathbb{C}}$ be open and connected and $f\in\mathcal{H}(U)$. 
Let $g\colon U\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function defined by $$g(z)=|f(z)|^{2}+f(z).$$
Show that if $g\in\mathcal{H}(U)$, then $f$ is constant.

The set of holomorphic functions in $ U $ is denoted by $ \mathcal {H} (U) $.

Attempt: As $ f, g \in \mathcal {H} (U), $ then $|f(z)|^{2} =g-f \in \mathcal{H} (U)$. In class, we saw the following:

Proposition (null derivative theorem for holomorphic functions): Let $U\subseteq{\mathbb{C}}$ be open and connected. If $f\in\mathcal{H}(U)$ y $f'(z)=0,\phantom{a}\forall z\in U$, then $f$ is constant.

Can I use that proposition and what I said before to ensure that $ f $ is constant?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: A non constant holomorphic function is an open map. If $g,f$ are holomorphic then so is $g-f$ and hence so is $x \mapsto |f(x)|^2$ and since this is holomorphic $f$ must be constant as it is not an open map. Hence $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $g-f$ is a real valued holomorphic function.

Comment: Yes, I know that $ g-f $ is  is a real valued holomorphic function, but it is variable. Then I don't know how to conclude...

Comment: @Darkmaster A real valued holomorphic function is always constant (consequence of the Cauchy–Riemann equations).

Comment: Yes, according to the Cauchy - Riemann equations, we have that g-f is constant. So, can I directly conclude that f is constant? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Darkmaster the comment of copper.hat above can give you the reasoning from there on. You have $ |f(x)| $ constant - this is the important relation.